# Why does PhpSpreadsheet fail to identify my Xlsx file in public://?

Tags: 8

I'm working on a module that imports a Xlsx file and inserts the rows to database. Everything works fine, except PhpSpreadsheet throws the error `Unable to identify a reader for this file` when my uploaded file is in `public`. This error doesn't happen when the file is in `base_path()`. Why is this happening? Below is my code:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $connection = \Drupal::database();
    $fid = $form_state->getValue("xlsx_upload");
    $input = File::load(reset($fid));
    $input->setPermanent();
    $uri = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($input->getFileUri());
    //$uri = '/home/joe/file.xslx'; <--- this works perfectly.
    $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReaderForFile($uri);
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($filename);
    $dataArray = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
    $connection->truncate("mitacan")->execute();
    $connection->query("SET NAMES utf8");
    foreach ($dataArray as $dataItem) {
      $connection->insert('mitacan')
      ->fields([
        'stokkodu'      => $dataItem[0],
        'logo'          => $dataItem[1],
        'resim1'        => $dataItem[2],
        'grupkodu'      => $dataItem[3],
        'grupadi'       => $dataItem[4],
        'grupindex'     => $dataItem[5],
        'paketadedi'    => $dataItem[6],
      ])
      ->execute();
    }
    drupal_set_message('Excel verisi veritabanına eklendi.');
  }
```

EDIT: The above code throws `"PHP message: Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "File "" does not exist ." at File.php line 137"`, even though line 137 throws an exception saying it's not a file, but `\dpm(is_file($uri))` returns TRUE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like PhpSpreadsheet can't read URIs, but only file paths.
You need to find the path to the file on the system.

```
$real_path_to_file = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($file->getFileUri());
```

*(Ideally you'd inject file_system and not call this service statically.)*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89162/discussion-on-answer-by-emil-johnsson-isaksson-why-does-phpspreadsheet-fail-to-i).

Comment: @Emil Johnsson your suggestion works just perfect.